# How can I break bricks?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I want to make a brick breaking game with Arduino. I want the ball to break and bounce whichever brick it hits above, but this does not happen with the code I wrote, where is my mistake?

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64

#define OLED_RESET     4
#define potPin        A0
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);

int paletBas = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
int paletBas_e = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
int palet_g = 20;
int palet_y = 4;
int topBoyut = 2;
int topX = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
int topX_e = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
int topY = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 25;
int topY_e = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 25;
int topDX = 1;
int topDY = -1;
int tugla_g = 12;
int tugla_y = 5;
int toplamTugla = SCREEN_WIDTH / (tugla_g + 2);
int t_Sira = 3;
bool tugla[3][20];
boolean game = true;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  if (!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C)) {
    Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed"));
    for (;;);
  }
  display.clearDisplay();
  tuglaVar();
}

void loop() 
{
 if(game)
 {
  tuglaCiz();
  paletCiz();
  topCiz();
  paletHareket();
  topHareket();

  boolean palet_kontrol = paletKontrol();
  boolean tugla_kontrol = tuglaKontrol();

  if(tugla_kontrol)
  {
    tuglaCiz();
  }
 }
}

void tuglaVar()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < t_Sira; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < toplamTugla; j++) {
      tugla[i][j] = true;
    }
  }
}

boolean tuglaKontrol()
{
  int topSol = topX - topBoyut; // Topun sol koordinatı
  int topSag = topX + topBoyut; // Topun sağ koordinatı
  int topUst = topY - topBoyut; // Topun üst koordinatı
  int topAlt = topY + topBoyut; // Topun alt koordinatı

  for (int i = 0; i < t_Sira; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < toplamTugla; j++) {
      if (tugla[i][j]) {
        int tuglaX = j * (tugla_g + 2);
        int tuglaY = i * (tugla_y + 2);

        if(topAlt >= tuglaY && topUst <= tuglaY + tugla_g){
          if(topSag >= tuglaX && topSol <= tuglaX + tugla_y){
            tugla[i][j] = false;
            topDY = -topDY;
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false; // Çarpışma olmadığını bildir
}

void tuglaCiz()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < t_Sira; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < toplamTugla; j++) {
      int tuglaX;
      int tuglaY;
      if (tugla[i][j]) {
        tuglaX = j * (tugla_g + 2);
        tuglaY = i * (tugla_y + 2);
        display.fillRect(tuglaX, tuglaY, tugla_g, tugla_y, WHITE);
      }
      else{
        display.fillRect(tuglaX, tuglaY, tugla_g, tugla_y, BLACK);
      }
    }
  }
  display.display();
}

void paletHareket()
{
  int potValue = analogRead(potPin);
  paletBas_e = paletBas;
  paletBas = map(potValue, 0, 1023, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH - palet_g);
}

boolean paletKontrol()
{
  if (topX >= paletBas && topX <= paletBas + palet_g && topY >= SCREEN_HEIGHT - 8 - topBoyut) {
    topDY = -topDY; // Palete çarptığında yön değiştir
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

void paletCiz()
{
  display.fillRect(paletBas_e, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 8, palet_g, palet_y, BLACK);
  display.fillRect(paletBas, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 8, palet_g, palet_y, WHITE);
}

void topHareket()
{
  topX_e = topX;
  topY_e = topY;
  topX += topDX; // Topu sağa doğru hareket ettir
  topY += topDY; // Topu yukarıya doğru hareket ettir

  if (topX >= SCREEN_WIDTH - topBoyut || topX <= topBoyut) {
    topDX = -topDX; // Duvarlara çarpınca yön değiştir
  }
  if (topY <= topBoyut) {
    topDY = -topDY; // Tavana çarpınca yön değiştir
  }
}

void topCiz()
{
  display.fillCircle(topX_e, topY_e, topBoyut, BLACK);
  display.fillCircle(topX, topY, topBoyut, WHITE);
}
```

I want to make a brick breaking game with Arduino. I want the ball to break and bounce whichever brick it hits above, but this does not happen with the code I wrote, where is my mistake?